# How to fix the shape of the numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have converted the image into a NumPy array. Then uses np.rot90 to rotate the array to 90 degrees.

```
img90 = np.array(np.rot90(image))
img90.shape
```

The output I receive is --> (256, 4, 256)
**But I want it to be (4, 256, 256)**

I have tried

```
img90 = np.rollaxis(img90, 1, 0)
img90.shape
```

But the output is not fixed, sometimes it gives (256, 4,256) and sometimes (4, 256, 256)

Comment: what is the input, and as far as I know code should return the same thing every time :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the axes `axes` and number of rotation `k` parameters

assuming your array size is `256x256x4`:

```
img0 = np.rot90(img0, axes=(0,2), k= 1)
print(img0.shape)
>>> (4, 256, 256)
```